# Craft CMS keep craft users logged between multiple environment

Tags: php, content-management-system, craftcms

I am trying to make a multi-environment website with Craft CMS with each environment being a different language. Is there a way to make my Craft Users stay logged in when clicking on a different language and changing environment. I have my two environment that look something like that in craft/config/general.php :

```
 'frenchSite' => array(
    'siteName' => 'French Site',
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://website-en.com',
        'fr' => 'http://website-fr.com',
    ),
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => '/home/vagrant/Projects/WebSite/dev/public/',
        'baseUrl'  => 'http://website-fr.com/', 
    ),
    'googleAnalyticCode' => '',
    'mailchimp' => '',
    'StripeID' => '',
    'GoogleMap' => '',
),

'EnglishSite' => array(
    'siteName' => 'English Site',   
    'devMode' => true,
    //'defaultCookieDomain' => 'website-fr.com',
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://website-en.com',
        'fr' => 'http://website-fr.com',
    ),
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => '/home/vagrant/Projects/WebSite/dev/public/',
        'baseUrl'  => 'http://website-en.com/', 
    ),
    'googleAnalyticCode' => '',
    'mailchimp' => '',
    'StripeID' => '',
    'GoogleMap' => '',
),
```